# Can I total a calculated field in a pivot table?

Tags: google-sheets, pivot-table, formula, spreadsheet

Is it possible to total a calculated field rather than just using it to summarize other fields?  For example, in this spreadsheet I want to round up any durations longer than 44 minutes.  So, if I work 45 minutes, I charge for an hour of work, $50/hr.

With that in mind, in the dataset below, I intend to charge for 2 total hours of work, but the Grand Total is only showing one total hour.  It's looking at the sum of each project's total, ignoring my "Hours Rounded" column.  Is what I'm trying to do possible?  Thanks.
[image: Screenshot showing pivot table.]